Is there a catalogue/record of every (or most) chemical reaction known to us?
I am not asking for types of chemical reactions. I know it is a Herculean task given that there are "more than 160 million chemicals are known to humans" but a catalogue/record (in a book/website/table etc) of rare/uncommon to basic chemical reactions would be sufficient.
Asking out of curiosity.

Oh actually, this would help so much! I am preparing for an olympiad and I want exposure of mechanisms which I can possibly understand while also being relatable. Meanwhile, I look up at the "see also" in Wikipedia which is hyperlinked at the end of every mechanism page.

IMHO, searching for  particular reactions in case of need is more efficient than creation, maintenance, finding, browsing, querying of such a database.
